# Infinite-dimensional version of Gram matrix is invertible

Tags: matrices, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

We all know that a Gram matrix (a matrix with entries that are inner products of basis functions) is a invertible. Suppose I have $a_{ij} = (h_i, h_j)_H$  where the $h_j$ are basis functions of a Hilbert space $H$. Is the infinite matrix $A=(a_{ij})$ invertible? That is, is $\sum_{j=1}^\infty a_{ij}v_i = b_i$ solvable for $v_i$ for each $i$ given $b_i$?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

For an arbitrary element $x$, let $x^* \in H^*$ denote $(\cdot,x)_H$.

Let $V$ denote the transformation
$$
Vx = \sum_{i} x_i h_i
$$
That is, $V$ is the matrix whose "column vectors" are the basis functions $h_i$.  Note that $A = V^*V$.

Now, note that for any $x$, $x^*(Ax) = (x^* V^*)(Vx) = (Vx)^*(Vx) = \|Vx\|_H^2$.  It follows that $Ax = 0$ if and only if $Vx = 0$.  Since $V$ has a basis as its columns, $V$ is indeed invertible.

Comment: thanks but I am confused about what $V$ is. $V:H \to H$ but how does $x_ih_I$ make sense??

Comment: Select an orthonormal basis $\{v_i\}$.  Define $V : H \to H$ by $\sum x_i v_i \mapsto \sum x_i h_i$; that is, by $v_i \mapsto h_i$.

Comment: ...........thank u